# UITableView repeat Custom Cell with UIView in different section after scroll down

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitableview

I have a ChartCell(UITableViewCell), it has an UIView that I use for showing a chart

```
class ChartCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemChart: ChartView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state

    }

}
```

but my UITableView repeat the cell after scroll down

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return items[section]["title"].stringValue
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: (header.textLabel?.font?.fontName)!, size: 13)!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 30.0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.items[section]["data"].count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch items[indexPath.section]["cell"]{
        case "bar" :

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bar", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChartCell
            cell.itemChart.data = items[indexPath.section]["data"][indexPath.row]
            cell.itemChart.total = items[indexPath.section]["total"].intValue
            return cell

        default :
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("issue", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IssueCell
            cell.itemDescription.text = items[indexPath.section]["data"][indexPath.row]["group_name"].stringValue
            cell.itemAmount.text = items[indexPath.section]["data"][indexPath.row]["ticket_count"].stringValue
            return cell
        }

    }

    func loadReport(sender : AnyObject) {

        let closedController = self
        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

        Services.getClosedReport({(status : Bool, data : JSON) -> Void in

            let tR = data["data"]["summary_by_resolution"]["data"] ?? []
            let tP = data["data"]["summary_by_priority"]["data"] ?? []
            let tI = data["data"]["summary_by_issue_type"]["data"] ?? []

            var totalR = 0

            for (_, subJson) in tR {
                if totalR < subJson["ticket_count"].intValue{
                    totalR = subJson["ticket_count"].intValue
                }
            }

            var totalP = 0

            for (_, subJson) in tP {
                if totalP < subJson["ticket_count"].intValue{
                    totalP = subJson["ticket_count"].intValue
                }
            }


            let tS = [
                JSON(["title" : "By Top 5 Resolution Types", "data" : tR , "cell" : "bar", "total" : JSON(totalR)]),
                JSON(["title" : "By Top 5 Issue Types", "data" : tI, "cell" : "issue"]),
                JSON(["title" : "By Priority", "data" : tP , "cell" : "bar", "total" : JSON(totalP)]),

            ]

            closedController.items = JSON(tS)
            self.itemReportTable.reloadData()
            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        })
    }
```

I debugged the tableView func for cellForRowAtIndexPath but the data is correct in each one section and row, the cell doesn't call the drawRect func of UIView into the custom cell, this last one repeat another cell in another section

UPDATE : 
the Custom UIView is the following:

```
class ChartView: UIView {

    var data : JSON!
    var total : Int!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let itemView = self
        let data  = itemView.data

        let corePoint = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
        let viewWidth = self.bounds.width
        let space = CGFloat(10.0)

        // MARK : -- Description

        let widthL = CGFloat(100.0)
        let heightL = CGFloat(20.0)
        let text = data["group_name"].stringValue

        let rectL = CGRectMake(corePoint.x, corePoint.y, widthL, heightL)
        let itemL = UILabel(frame: rectL)
        itemL.text = text
        itemL.font = UIFont(name: itemL.font.fontName, size: 13.0)
        itemView.addSubview(itemL)


        // MARK : -- CGRect

        let heightR = CGFloat(30.0)
        let toY = (heightR - heightL) / 2.0

        let yR = corePoint.y - toY
        let xR = corePoint.x + widthL + space
        let rect = CGRectMake(xR, yR, 0, heightR)
        let itemR = UIView(frame: rect)
        itemR.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255, blue: 169.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        itemView.addSubview(itemR)


        // MARK : -- Amount

        let widthA = widthL
        let heightA = heightL
        let textA = data["ticket_count"].stringValue

        let xA = xR + space
        let yA = corePoint.y

        let rectA = CGRectMake(xA, yA, widthA, heightA)
        let itemA = UILabel(frame: rectA)
        itemA.text = textA
        itemA.font = UIFont(name: itemA.font.fontName, size: 13.0)
        itemView.addSubview(itemA)


        // MARK : -- Animation


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in

            let widthT = (viewWidth - xR - 50) * CGFloat(data["ticket_count"].intValue) / CGFloat(self.total)

            itemR.frame = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(xR, yR, widthT, heightR), 0.0, 0.0)
            itemA.frame.origin.x = xA + widthT + 5.0

        }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `getClosedReport` runs in the background, so you must update the UI on the main thread using `dispatch_async`. This may not be your problem, because it's not clear how this gets called or when.

Comment: what is the type of `itemChart`? is it a subClass of `UIView`?  is its  drawRect func be called? if not, you can try to call the cell.itemChart.setNeedsDisplay() func.

Comment: @Michael, exactly getClosedReport run an call to service with Alamofire, when i get this data I have 3 sections, the two firsts sections use the same Custom Cell, in this case 'bar'. iphone 4s show only the first section but when scroll down the second sections show the same rows in the first section, iphone 6 show the two firsts sections but in the second section shows only 3 then when i scroll down the next two rows repeat the rows in the first section

Comment: @zhubch I added `setNeedsDisplay` but each one row render over the previously graphic